Implement xmla server from scratch
Anyone is the world has ever did a server side xmla protocol project ?
Im trying to create one in python poc but struggling just to get into the first step
First query from excel is:
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <RequestType>DISCOVER_PROPERTIES</RequestType>
            <Restrictions>
                <RestrictionList>
                    <PropertyName>
                        <Value>DbpropMsmdSubqueries</Value>
                        <Value>DbpropMsmdOptimizeResponse</Value>
                        <Value>DbpropMsmdActivityID</Value>
                        <Value>DbpropMsmdCurrentActivityID</Value>
                        <Value>ApplicationContext</Value>
                    </PropertyName>
                </RestrictionList>
            </Restrictions>
            <Properties>
                <PropertyList/>
            </Properties>
        </Discover>

And i tried to give him a response following documentation in XMLA Microsoft but still failing, excel saying error "The syntax for '' is incorrect. ()."
    <DiscoverResponse xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
        <return>
            <root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
                <row>
                    <DbpropMsmdSubqueries>0</DbpropMsmdSubqueries>
                    <DbpropMsmdOptimizeResponse>0</DbpropMsmdOptimizeResponse>
                    <DbpropMsmdActivityID>CCC4C4D7-0BF2-416B-A15E-520D307F4FFC</DbpropMsmdActivityID>
                    <DbpropMsmdCurrentActivityID>CCC4C4D7-0BF2-416B-A15E-520D307F4FFC</DbpropMsmdCurrentActivityID>
                    <ApplicationContext/>
                </row>a
            </root>
        </return>
    </DiscoverResponse>

Any help would be awesome !
